# SQL Query with multiple JOINS and junction table

Tags: mysql

I'm working with MySQL on this query and struggling a bit. The joins make sense to me but getting the data out of the images table which has a junction table called user_image seems difficult and I just can't grasp it.

```
SELECT c.id, c.city, ROUND(( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(27.9861) ) *
              cos( radians( lat ) ) *
              cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-80.6628) ) +
              sin( radians(27.9861) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ),0) AS distance,
       t.id, t.name, t.price, t.duration, d.description, u.fname,
       i.image_path, i.image_name
FROM city c
    JOIN trip t ON c.id = t.city_id
    JOIN trip_description d ON t.id = d.trip_id
    JOIN user u ON t.user_id = u.id
    -- Need to get all images that match trip and is_main = 1
HAVING distance < 20 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 45;
```

My image tables look like this...

- **user_image:** trip_id | image_id
- **image:** id | image_name | is_active | is_main

Not sure if I'm supposed to be using another join, a union, a query in a query? Really at a loss, would appreciate some help :)

Comment: The geo portion of the query was from an example by Google, they used 'having' in their example so that's why it's there. Does that make a difference for trying to get data out of the image table?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it. Here's the working example. Thanks to everyone that responded.

```
SELECT c.id, c.city, ROUND(( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(27.9861) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-80.6628) ) + sin( radians(27.9861) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ),0) AS distance, t.id, t.name, t.price, t.duration, d.description, u.fname, i.path, i.name
FROM city c
    JOIN trip t ON c.id = t.city_id
    JOIN trip_description d ON t.id = d.trip_id
    JOIN user u ON t.user_id = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_image ui ON ui.trip_id = t.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN image i ON ui.image_id = i.id
    AND i.main=1
HAVING distance < 20 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 45;
```

Comment: You might also want to add the `id` column to the `ORDER BY` clause like `ORDER BY distance, id` assuming id column is a primary key you would always get a deterministic (fixed) resultset always.. As in cases where distance "ties" you get non deterministic (random) results where distance  are the same so you don't know city A will be first, second or third and so on if that matters..